# Clusters of variables interpretation

Tags: r, clustering

I am doing clustering of variables using `hclustvar()` function from ClustOfVar package in R. The example given in R for the decathlon data is:

```
data(decathlon)

tree <- hclustvar(X.quanti=decathlon[,1:10], init=NULL)

plot(tree)
```

The function does the PCA and then analyze projections of variables on main components to detect those variables that have similar coordinates. However I still don't know **how to interprete the Y-axis on the plot which is called Height**. Could anybody help me with the interpretation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As stated on the [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ClustOfVar/ClustOfVar.pdf) – p.9, `hclustvar()` provides ascendant hierarchical clustering of a set of variables. In order to do this hierarchical clustering, it should compute a distance metric between variables and clusters. In the case of `hclustvar()`, this distance is based on correlation between variables and then between clusters – i.e group of variables (cf. the *aggregation criterion* defined in the package documentation. For more information, look at the paper dedicated to the package on jstatsoft. Paper title: *ClustOfVar: An R Package for the Clustering of Variables*).

The Y-axis (Height) is the value of this distance metric. If you see two clusters merged at a height *x*, it means that the distance between those clusters is `x`. Here for example, the minimal height is `0.3842319` and this is the distance between `Shop.put` and `Discus` which are the closest variables. This distance is equal to `1 - cor(decathlon$Shot.put, decathlon$Discus)`. Note that `length(tree$height) ==  n-1`, with `n` being the number of variables, since you need at least two variables to generate the first cluster.

Comment: Seems not mention how it is involved with PCA